# Column manipulation R

Tags: python, r, loops, debugging, iteration

I'm pretty new to working with R and I was hoping someone could point me in the right way. I have a data set in the form of a tibble, and I need to go through each row.
In each row I have to check columns in sets of 3.
i.e if one of the columns value=0 I have to delete all three columns and evaluate the next 3 columns.

```
data_set <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=2))
data_set$Basket1<- c(45,35)
data_set$Type1 <- c("Normal","Premium")
data_set$Amount1 <- c(4,5)

data_set$Basket2 <- c(4,98)
data_set$Type2 <- c("Normal","Normal")
data_set$Amount2 <- c(0,4)

#when Type is "Premium" I want to remove the values for 
#Basket1,Type1,Amount1 
#and shift the next 3 cells to the left
```

Comment: Please include a reproducible example showing some example data, the code you have tried so far, and the output you're expecting.

Comment: when you say "delete all three columns" do you mean what it sounds like? eg if any row of the column has a zero, all three columns are removed from the table altogether?  Or do you just mean the values in that one row become NA?

Comment: @Zoe, please post samples in your posts, comments are NOT meant for that, let us know once you do so.

Comment: Sorry, just updated the post. Not sure how to format the data to a table in the post. First time using this

Comment: @Zoe for reference on creating a reproducible example in R you can check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: What evaluation do you want to do?

Comment: @Onyambu I just updated the post :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 updated the post

Comment: @PeterEllis hi I just updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments to my previous answer, here is another way of doing it that is robust to not knowing the number of columns in advance.  In this situation it always pays to first convert the data into a known shape, and the only shape it can be in this situation is a long thin one.  Once you've got it in that condition, you can group it by customer id and do whatever manipulations you need that way:

```
library(tidyverse)

data_set %>%

  # add a unique identifier for the original shape:
  mutate(customer = 1:n()) %>%

  # turn into a long thin format:
  gather(variable, value, -customer) %>%

  # remove any NA values from the unbalanced table (and the empty column at the beginning of the original)
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%

  # extract the numbers from the original column names:
  mutate(column_set = as.numeric(str_extract(variable, "[0-9]+")),
         variable = gsub("[0-9]+", "", variable)) %>%

  # limit the data to the first "normal" column set for each customer
  group_by(customer) %>%
  mutate(best_column_set = min(column_set[value == "Normal"])) %>%
  filter(column_set == best_column_set) %>%

  # drop the columns we don't need and return to wide format:
  select(-column_set, -best_column_set) %>%
  spread(variable, value) %>%

  # convert from characters back to numbers
  mutate(Basket = as.numeric(Basket),
         Amount = as.numeric(Amount))
```

This returns:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   customer [2]
  customer Amount Basket Type  
     <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> 
1        1      4     45 Normal
2        2      4     98 Normal
```

This method depends on their being quite some structure in how the original columns are labelled; for example that they are numbered by column set, and that there aren't any other numbers in the column names.

Comment: Is there an email address I can contact you or is that frowned upon on here? I feel like I have confused everyone and I can explain it better with an excel file

Comment: sure.  peter.ellis2013nz at gmail dot com

Comment: Thanks. Sent you an email.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my update at the end based on the new example you added.

```
#I have a data set in the form of a tibble
data_set              <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=8))
data_set$column1_set1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
data_set$column2_set1 <- c(1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1)
data_set$column3_set1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

data_set$column1_set2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
data_set$column2_set2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
data_set$column3_set2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
data_set$V1           <- NULL

data_set <- as.tibble(data_set)

# In each row I have to check columns in sets of 3. 
#   i.e if one of the columns value=0 I have to delete all three columns 
#   and evaluate the next 3 columns.
```

You can do so like this:

```
cn               <- colnames(data_set)

for(i in seq(1,length(cn),3)){
  if(any(colSums(data_set[,i:(i+2)]) < nrow(data_set))){
    data_set <- data_set[,!colnames(data_set) %in% cn[i:(i+2)]]

  } else{
    next
  }
}
```

In the new example we have some non-numeric columns. The only change we have to make is to check if they are numeric first.

```
cn               <- colnames(data_set)

for(i in seq(1,length(cn),3)){

    cn_tmp   <- cn[i:(i+2)]
    cn_tmp   <- ifelse(class(data_set[,colnames(data_set) %in% cn_tmp])=="numeric",
                       cn_tmp, cn_tmp[!cn_tmp==cn_tmp[i]])
    cn_tmp   <- ifelse(class(data_set[,colnames(data_set) %in% cn_tmp])=="numeric",
                       cn_tmp, cn_tmp[!cn_tmp==cn_tmp[i+1]])
    cn_tmp   <- ifelse(class(data_set[,colnames(data_set) %in% cn_tmp])=="numeric",
                       cn_tmp, cn_tmp[!cn_tmp==cn_tmp[i+2]])

  if(any(colSums(data_set[,colnames(data_set) %in% cn_tmp]) < nrow(data_set))){
    data_set <- data_set[,!colnames(data_set) %in% cn[i:(i+2)]]

  } else{
    next
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I updated the post with formatted code and comments

Comment: @Zoe OK based on your example I will edit my solution to check if the column is numeric

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend not thinking in terms of shifting values leftwards or rightwards - it's not making the most of R's data frame objects, where the columns should be seen as having integrity.  So instead of shifting and deleting cells, I think you should add new columns to the right based on the logic you need and then (if necessary) delete all the original columns.  Here's one way to do this, creating new amount_n, basket_n and type_n columns and discarding the rest at the end:

```
library(dplyr)
data_set <- data_set %>%
  mutate(
    basket_n = case_when(
      # If Type1 is Normal we use its basket:
      Type1 == "Normal" ~ Basket1,
      # If not, then see if Type2 is normal and we can use that (and so on):
      Type2 == "Normal" ~ Basket2
    ),
    amount_n = case_when(
      Type1 == "Normal" ~ Amount1,
      Type2 == "Normal" ~ Amount2
    ),
    type_n = "Normal"
  ) %>%
  select(type_n, basket_n, amount_n)
```

Comment: How do I change this so that I don't have to refer to the column name? This is an unbalanced table so each row can have different multiples of 3 column sets. For ex: if each row is a customer the 3 column set could be different baskets they bought. Different customers can have different number of baskets.

Comment: You've lost me I'm afraid.  Are you saying you don't know how many columns you have in advance? (because it is defined dynamically and you are trying to automate this)?

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't know how many column columns each row has. I'm trying to run association rules so the end goal is to have only the values for Basket for each record. So for data cleaning I have to remove the "baskets" where Type=Premium or Type=Normal and Amount=0

Comment: I would take a different approach, more like a database developer, and normalise the data into a long thin version.  I'll do a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
data=read.table(text="   Basket1 Type1   Amount1 Basket2 Type2   Amount2 Basket3 Type3   Amount3
1   Normal  1   10  Normal  3   12  Premium 0
2   Normal  0   3   Normal  3   45  Premium 3
3   Normal  1   3   Normal  3   3   Premium 67
4   Normal  1   5   Normal  3   54  Premium 45",h=T)
```

to shift left, you can do:

```
data%>%
  rownames_to_column%>%
  reshape(matrix(2:ncol(.),3),idvar = 1,dir="long")%>%
  filter(!rowSums(.==0)>0)%>%
  group_by(rowname)%>%
  mutate(time=1:n())%>%
  arrange(time,rowname)%>%
  data.frame()%>%
  reshape(timevar = "time",idvar = "rowname",dir="wide")%>%
  select(-rowname)%>%
      rename_all(~sub("\\d.","",.x))

 Basket1  Type1 Amount1 Basket2   Type2 Amount2 Basket3   Type3 Amount3
1       1 Normal       1      10  Normal       3      NA    <NA>      NA
2       3 Normal       3      45 Premium       3      NA    <NA>      NA
3       3 Normal       1       3  Normal       3       3 Premium      67
4       4 Normal       1       5  Normal       3      54 Premium      45
```

EDIT::

For the data that you provided later:

```
data_set[-1]%>%
   rownames_to_column%>%
   reshape(matrix(2:ncol(.),3),idvar = 1,dir="long")%>%
   filter(!rowSums(.==0)>0)%>%
   group_by(rowname)%>%mutate(time=1:n())%>%
   arrange(time,rowname)%>%
   data.frame()%>%
   reshape(timevar = "time",idvar = "rowname",dir="wide")%>%
   select(-rowname)%>%
   rename_all(~sub("\\d.","",.x))

  Basket1   Type1 Amount1 Basket2  Type2 Amount2
1      45  Normal       4      NA   <NA>      NA
2      35 Premium       5      98 Normal       4
```